# When does onmouseout occur?

Tags: javascript, events, onmouseout

I mean does it occur every single moment when the mouse is not over the element? Or is it a single action when mouse leaves the element? It is important because I need to know when the mouse pointer leaves the element, but I need to know only when it enters again. I don't want my script to run over and over again while the mouse pointer is not over the element.

Comment: Only when the mouse comes in and **goes out of the element**.

Answer (score 0):

> The mouseout event fires when the user moves the mouse out of an element. Unfortunately these events bubble up.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

If you do not want the event to bubble up, add `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: how do you mean they bubble up?

Comment: @dawe69hun Bubbling up is like, say you have a parent and a child getting the same end of the container. And you move out. Both the parent's mouseout and the child's mouseout will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

> The mouseout event is raised when the mouse leaves an element (e.g,
>   when the mouse moves off of an image in the web page, the mouseout
>   event is raised for that image element).

**Source:** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onmouseout)

This would imply that it only occurs once and not continuously, since the mouse can only move off of the element at a single point in time.  Once the mouse is off the element the event has been fired.